# Como armazenar números em um vetor para exibi-lo depois em C?

Tags: c, array, loop

Eu tenho que fazer um código em que o usuário digita 20 valores, devo contar os valores maiores que 10 e então exibi-los depois. Estou conseguindo contar quantos valores são maiores que 10, porém a parte de exibir estes valores não funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <locale.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <string.h>



main () {

int vet[5],i,contador=0, num[5],j;


   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

    printf("Digite o valor %i:",i+1);

    scanf("%i",&vet[i]);

    if (vet[i]>=10)
    {
        contador++;


    }

    }
 for (j=0;j<5;j++)

    {
        if (vet[i]>=10)
        {
            printf("Estes são os valores maiores que 10:%i",vet[i]);
        }

    }

    printf("Há este total de numeros maiores que 10:%i\n\n", contador);

}
```

Comment: Talvez aqui: ` for (j=0;j<5;j++)

    {
        if (vet[i]>=10)
        {
            printf("Estes são os valores maiores que 10:%i",vet[i]);
        }

    }
` o índice deva ser `j` não?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um problema é que não está lendo 20 mas apenas 5. Ok, pode ser que fez assim só para facilitar. Mas ficar mais fácil usar uma definição que pode trocar em todos lugares com facilidade.

Está criando todas variáveis antes e fazendo elas serem globais para toda função. Isso é ensinado por muitos, mas é algo antigo, não faz mais sentido fazer isso, quando faz a variável ter o menos escopo possível pode errar menos. Esse caso no segundo laço usou uma variável que não é daquele laço, então ela pega uma área da memória inválida porque é a variável do outro laço. Mantendo as variáveis mais restritas onde elas estão usadas pode facilitar e evitar esse tip ode erro porque pode usar o mesmo nome e ser variáveis diferentes.

E ainda mudou o operador de comparação porque o enunciado fala em valores maiores que 10 e não ou que são iguais, um dos dois estava errado, mudei o código.

E claro, simplifiquei e organizei mais o código. preste atenção em todos os detalhes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 20

int main () {
    int vet[MAX];
    int contador = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        printf("Digite o valor %i:",i+1);
        scanf("%i", &vet[i]);
        if (vet[i] > 10) contador++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) if (vet[i] > 10) printf("Estes são os valores maiores que 10: %d\n", vet[i]);
    printf("Há este total de numeros maiores que 10: %d", contador);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/k0a7YK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/emfjmvpe-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Filter2.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado, Maniero. Sim, eu havia definido em 5 para fazer os testes. Vou estudar este código e aplicar nos demais para que eu possa aprender.